# ADB failed to detect Nexus 5 running Android Marshmallow

Tags: adb, nexus-5, connection-issues, usb-debugging, 6.0-marshmallow

File transfer is working properly.
Latest drivers are installed.
Settings -> Developer options (Enabled)
Android Debugging (Enabled)

(ADB Detects my phone when it is in Recovery mode)

So probably there is something wrong in the system.

I'm using Pure Nexus ROM + Nethunter

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Which build of PureNexus ROM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advise to install **Universal naked drivers** on your Windows system as in windows only we encounter such driver issues.

Refer this link for Universal naked drivers: http://www.xda-developers.com/universal-naked-driver-solves-your-adb-driver-problems-on-windows/

Being a Nexus 5 user, I have encountered this problem and after great efforts, UND helped.
You can install the drivers by downloading zip file, unpacking it.
Connect your N5 to your PC, go to "Device Manager" in windows, uninstalling the already installed Nexus 5 Drivers. Install drivers by provided options and use the location of unzipped files when it asks for manual installation of drivers.

Comment: OP wrote "*ADB Detects my phone when it is in Recovery mode*", so definitely, the problem doesn't appear to be about drivers.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem can be resolved switching the USB mode to only charge/data transfer via MTP. It works on my device.

Comment: And how is the OP supposed to do this? Please elaborate your answer by **editing it**.